# ASP.net MVC 3 project files not showing up in new project dialog?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I installed ASP.net MVC 3 on my dev machine yesterday using the web-based installer, did a clean reboot, etc.

The MVC 3 projects still don't appear in my New Project dialog, only the MVC 2 ones. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 7):

The answer (in this case): Make sure you have the .net 4 runtime selected at the top of the new project dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio 2008, it won't show up since it's available for VS 2010 / .NET 4 only. If however you are using VS 2010 and .NET 4, they should appear unless something wonky occurred with the install.

Comment: As specified in the tags, this is Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I really want to reply with "As specified in the answer, then you have a wonky install" but that would just sound snarky. :)